# Bash Script if a file exists and larger than loop

Tags: linux, bash

*Note i edited this so my final functioning code is below

Ok so I'm writing a bash script to backup our mysql database to a directory, delete the oldest backup if 10 exist, and output the results of the backup to a log so I can further create alerts if it fails.  Everything works great except the if loop to output the results, thanks again for the help guys code is below!

```
#! /bin/bash
#THis creates a variable with the date stamp to add to the filename
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%y")
#This moves the bash shell to the directory of the backups
cd /dbbkp/backups/
#Counts the number of files in the direstory with the *.sql extension and deletes the oldest once 10 is reached.
[[ $(ls -ltr *.sql | wc -l) -gt 10 ]] && rm $(ls -ltr *.sql | awk 'NR==1{print $NF}')
#Moves the bash shell to the mysql bin directory to run the backup script
cd /opt/GroupLink/everything_HelpDesk/mysql/bin/
#command to run and dump the mysql db to the directory
./mysqldump -u root -p dbname > /dbbkp/backups/ehdbkp_$now.sql --protocol=socket --socket=/tmp/GLmysql.sock --password=password

#Echo the results to the log file

#Change back to the directory you created the backup in
cd /dbbkp/backups/

#If loop to check if the backup is proper size and if it exists
if find ehdbkp_$now.sql -type f -size +51200c 2>/dev/null | grep -q .; then 
echo "The backup has run successfully" >> /var/log/backups
else
echo "The backup was unsuccessful" >> /var/log/backups
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by "proper size" ?

Comment: I want to make sure the DB file is at or greater than expected, basically i want to make sure the dump doesn't fail and it doesn't just create an empty file or fail part way through creating a smaller file.  Right now I have it set to just 50mb

Comment: Just as an aside, you could also use `pushd` and `popd` instead of the latter two `cd`s. That is, `pushd /opt/GroupLink/everything_HelpDesk/mysql/bin` ... run and dump ... echo ... `popd`. Nothing to do with your question, just something I noticed.

Comment: There is no `AND` in bash; it's `-a`. And there is no such thing as an "if loop" in any language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if the file exists and larger than 51200 bytes you could rewrite your `if` like this:

```
if find ehdbkp_$now -type f -size +51200c 2>/dev/null | grep -q .; then
    echo "The backup has run successfully"
else
    echo "The backup has was unsuccessful"
fi >> /var/log/backups
```

Other notes:

- The `find` takes care two things at once: checks if file exists and size is greater than 51200.
- We redirect stderr to `/dev/null` to hide the error message if the file doesn't exist.
- If there was a file matching both conditions, then `grep` will match and exit with success, otherwise it will exit with failure
- The final outcome of the `grep` is what decides the `if` condition
- I moved the `>> /var/log/backups` after the closing `fi`, as it's equivalent this way and less duplication.

Btw `if` is NOT a loop, it's a conditional.

**UPDATE**

As [@glennjackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) pointed out, a better way to write the `if`, without `grep`:

```
if [[ $(find ehdbkp_$now -type f -size +51200c 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
...
```

Comment: Without having to spawn grep, you could also say: `if [[ $(find ehdbkp_$now -type f -size +51200c 2>/dev/null) ]]; ...` -- success if the output from find is not empty.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you could use `stat` instead of `find`.

```
if [ $(stat -c %s ehdbkp_$now 2>/dev/null || echo 0) -gt 51200 ]; then
    echo "The backup has run successfully"
else
    echo "The backup was unsuccessful"
fi >> /var/log/backups
```

Option `-c %s` tells `stat` to return the size of file in bytes. This will take care of both the presence of file and size greater than 51200. When the file is missing, `stat` will err out, thus we redirect error message to `/dev/null`. The logical or condition `||` will get executed only when the file is missing thus the comparison will make `[ 0 -gt 100 ]` false.